# BigQuery load config variables from a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table defining constants in a single row. I want to construct a query on another table by using the value of these constants, something like:

> SELECT DataTable.name  FROM DataTable WHERE DataTable.key >
>   Config.keyConstant

but I have no idea how I can do this cleanly. In this case it could be done by using a CROSS JOIN

> SELECT DataTable.name  FROM (DataTable CROSS JOIN Config) WHERE DataTable.key >
>   Config.keyConstant

But this gets really messy as my queries get larger and the config is needed in different places.

Any suggestions? In SQL I'd think you'd do this with variables.

EDIT: Actually I want to be able to do something like

> SELECT IF(Config.keyConstant*DataTable.key=1, DataTable.name, "John")  FROM DataTable

This means that unfortunately I can't move all of the conditional logic into a WHERE EXISTS clause like suggested in an answer (although I wasn't aware of this, and it is cool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are in the right direction:

Something like below should work for both BigQuery Legacy and Standard SQL and having that Config has just one row makes CROSS JOIN not that bad looking.

```
SELECT DataTable.name 
FROM DataTable 
CROSS JOIN Config
WHERE DataTable.key1 > Config.key1Constant
  AND DataTable.key2 = Config.key2Constant
  AND DataTable.key3 < Config.key3Constant
```

In BigQuery Standard SQL you can change this to below, which somehow looks to me a little bit more portable:

```
SELECT
  DataTable.name
FROM DataTable
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM config
  WHERE DataTable.key1 > key1Constant
    AND DataTable.key2 = key2Constant
    AND DataTable.key3 < key3Constant
)
```

Few notes:

- cost wise  - even though Config table is small  - each time it will be contributing extra 10MB to the billing bytes
- having extra column(s) in Config (like id ) will allow you to manage different versions of constants to be used by calling specific id value. Or condition based logic can be used to invoke needed constants

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I'm going to edit my question as my given example is solved by your solution, but an extension I had in mind isn't.

Comment: it is up to you  - but instead of adjusting/changing current question i would suggest posting new one with details about your extension

Comment: Thanks.. It seems so related that it is worth just keeping them together.

Comment: I've ended up using something like this. It is a bit messy.. but it works :-) So thanks. Marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is to answer updated question:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Config.keyConstant*DataTable.key=1 
       THEN DataTable.name ELSE "John"
  END as name
FROM DataTable 
CROSS JOIN Config
```

Comment: Thanks - Again the issue is basically about finding a cleaner solution. I have nested sub-selects etc, and really want something equivalent to a variable definition. Maybe this is the best solution though.

Comment: unfortunatelly BigQuery does not support variables. you can submit your case here https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=463&q=variable